# Can't connect to remote dockerized pulsar server

Tags: docker, apache-pulsar

I've set up a dockerized pulsar server on a remote machine, which I'm connected to via VPN on ip address 172.21.11.82. On my local machine, I'm running the pulsar client to try to connect to the remote pulsar server on url pulsar://172.21.11.82:6650. However, I keep getting an operation timed out.

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM apachepulsar/pulsar:2.6.0
EXPOSE 6650 8080
CMD bin/pulsar standalone
```

And I'm running the container with:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 6650:6650 pulsar
```

Comment: Most likely, this has nothing to do with the application but with the network setup.

Comment: Does it work if you ssh to the remote machine and connect to `pulsar://localhost:6650`?  Does it work if you `docker exec` into the container and connect from there?  Does the container print out any startup messages, especially anything that looks like "listening on 127.0.0.1:6650"?